# Загрузка и замена содержимого в модальном окне

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, bootstrap

Есть ссылки вида (data внутри отличаются)

```
<a class="btn btn-primary" data-bname="Наименование" data-bimg="2.jpg" data-bprice="5080" href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Смотреть</a>
```

и js

```
<script>
    $(function() {
     $(".bt1n").click(
       function() {
         var bname = null;
         var bimg = null;
         var bprice = null;
         bname = $(this).attr('data-bname');
         bimg = $(this).attr('data-bimg');
         bprice = $(this).attr('data-bprice');

         $(".kartka h1").text(bname);
         $(".kartka img").attr('src', bimg);
         $(".kartka p").html(bprice);
       })
   });
    </script>
```

Сюда все выводится

```
        <div class="kartka">
  <h1></h1>
  <img src="" alt="" />
  <p></p>
```

Вопрос заключается в том как сделать загрузку разного содержимого в модальное окно и очистку при закрытии модального окна. Сейчас почему то получается просто замена.

Другими словами как мне загружать несколько фотографий по одной ссылке, а при нажатии на другую я бы мог грузить только 1 фотографию и текст.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

К сожалению не нашел пока решения всех проблем, но для вывода дополнительных изображений в кнопку добавил новую data для каждого нужного изображения. То есть если при клике на кнопку в модали должно быть 3 изображения, то к кнопке прикрепляем 3 разные data

Пример

```
<a class="btn btn-primary" data-bname="Название" data-bimg="1.jpg" data-bimg2="2.jpg" data-bprice="5080" href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Приобрести</a>
```

После редактируем js

```
<script>
$(function() {
 $(".btn").click(
   function() {
     var bname = null;
     var bimg = null;
     var bimg2 = null;
     var bprice = null;
     bname = $(this).attr('data-bname');
     bimg = $(this).attr('data-bimg');
     bimg2 = $(this).attr('data-bimg2');
     bprice = $(this).attr('data-bprice');

     $(".kartka h1").text(bname);
     $(".kartka img").attr('src', bimg);
     $(".k img").attr('src', bimg2);
     $(".kartka p").html(bprice);
   })
});
</script>
```

Где  `var bimg2 = null;` мы обнулили переменную (или как правильно называется)

```
bimg2 = $(this).attr('data-bimg2');
```

Забрали все из нашей data и поместили в переменну

```
$(".k img").attr('src', bimg2);
```

Тут мы указали что все что есть в bimg2 должно появляться в классе к внутри img

И теперь добавляем в модальное окно место, где появится наша картинка

```
<div class="k"><img src="" alt="" /></div>
```